# Changing the Key Exchange Algorithm used by OpenSSH Server

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to SSH to a certain a Linux machine (that's running OpenSSH-Server) from a Cisco IOS XE device. However, I'm getting

```
Jan 08 15:22:39 localhost.localdomain sshd[2041]: Unable to negotiate with 10.*.*.* port 16385: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
```

How can I fix that by allowing incoming sessions with less secure Key Exchange Algorithms?

I looked into https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html but they're only covering outgoing connections to legacy devices, not the opposite.

Thank you,

Comment: Try `man sshd` on the target. The target is not accepting insecure key negotiations it seems. You'll have to enable them, but better: get your client updated if possible.

Comment: I did, nothing helpful. I'm running the latest version of IOS XE, Cisco (weirdly) is running a very old SSH stack.

Comment: So you could lower the security of Linux by installing an older version of OpenSSH. It seems the current versions only accept SHA-2.

Comment: I just noticed your comment, but I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

This is possible without downgrading your sshd.
You have to add `KexAlgorithms` to your `sshd_config` file (tested this on Ubuntu server 22).

After that you might still be experiencing some errors, like `no matching host key type found`.
You then need to specify those under "HostkeyAlgorithms".

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
```

I'm not sure if you can enable these for certain clients only.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using   `"ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 username@IPAddress"`